# Friend Class and Inheritance

Tags: c++

I have a `friend` `class B` of my `class A`,
Is it possible that `B`'s ancesstor can also access `A`'s functionality or this friendship is only between `A` and `B` strictly

Comment: B and A only, but why use friendship?

Comment: friendship is only between `A` and `B`.

Comment: Did you try to find that out by coding yourself?

Comment: While coding , i was cautious about my class hierarchy ,This is my doubt as I dont want access from anyother class except B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, friendship is not inherited. In future I suggest you try such things out before posting a question.

Comment: Sure, Will keep in mind,I was on the way to my home and this doubt came, so shared :)